# Need a bit column an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a Sql Server table with millions of records.
I have a field of type Bit Not null called "deleted_rec".
All my queries have "where deleted_rec = 0"

The question is, definitely, must the field deleted_rec be indexed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, a bit field index wont take up much space and has the potential of speeding up your queries.  Why dont you add it and see how it affects the speed?

Comment: This actually depends on selectivity. What's the number of 0s vs 1s in deleted_rec column? Might check the filtered indexes also.